# Remove duplicate rows dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove the rows from df1 which are also found in df2 in the same column.

df1 have additional columns compared to df2 which I have not included here to simplify the question

```
df1 = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2022', end='1/04/2022', freq='D')
df2 = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2022', end='1/08/2022', freq='D')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['date'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['date'])

# this line does not remove the duplicates
df3 = df2.drop_duplicates(df1.columns[0:])
```

The final result should be

```
   0 2022-01-05
   1 2022-01-06
   2 2022-01-07
   3 2022-01-08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Drop columns in df1 which are also found in df2**

```
df1.drop(columns=df2.columns, errors='ignore', inplace=True)
```

or

```
df1 =  df1.drop(columns=df2.columns, errors='ignore')
```

**Drop rows in df1 and also in df2 in a specific column say date**

Following your edit, if it is a single column like date, please try

```
df1[~df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])]
```

If it is a check on multiple columns, it can also be done. However, we will need more info. **What happens if column1 in both df has same values in df1 and df2 and in the same row a column2 in both df has different values.?**

Comment: `inplace` is kinda getting deprecated though...I think you should do `df = df.drop(...)` instead. :)

Comment: It removes all the columns from df1 instead of the rows, sorry it was my mistake that I have not specified in the question, I have edited the question.

Comment: A minute, will edit for you

Comment: `df2[~df2['date'].isin(df1['date'])]` should remove all rows in df2 that are in df1

Comment: Does that resolve the issue or not?

Comment: @wwnde your third option is working, but it needs to be like this 
df2[~df2['date'].isin(df1['date'])]  
otherwise it removes the non duplicate entries

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicates` only works for rows. If you want to remove columns from one df that are in another df, use `~df2.columns.isin(df1.columns)` to return False for columns that are in `df1` (`False` = should not be kept), and `True` for columns that are not in `df1` (`True` = should be kept).  Then pass the resulting column mask to `.loc`, **at the second position**.

This line will remove the columns from `df2` that are in `df1`:

```
df2 = df2.loc[:, ~df2.columns.isin(df1.columns)]
```

Comment: sorry it was my mistake that I have not specified in the question, I have edited the question. I want to remove the rows from df1 which are also found in df2 in the same column